# Evaluate the following integral using the substitution $x=9\sinh^2\theta$ $\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{x+9}{x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, hyperbolic-functions

> Evaluate the following integral using the substitution $x=9\sinh^2\theta$ 
>   $$\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{x+9}{x}}dx$$

So I have attempted this integral but, I've made a mistake somewhere and I cannot see anything wrong with what I've done, my workings are:

If $x=9\sinh^2\theta$, then $x+9 = 9\cosh^2\theta$ and $dx = 18\sinh\theta\cosh\theta \,d\theta$
$$\int \sqrt{\frac{9\cosh^2\theta}{9\sinh^2\theta}} \times 9\sinh\theta\cosh\theta \,d\theta$$
$$9\int \cosh^2\theta\, d\theta $$
Now using the identity that $\cosh^2\theta = \frac12 (\cosh2\theta +1)$, the integral becomes $$\frac92\int (\cosh2\theta +1 )\,d\theta$$
$$\frac92 \left[ \frac12 \sinh2\theta + \theta\right] = \frac92 \left[ \sinh\theta\cosh\theta + \theta\right]$$
The after messing around with some algebra, I got to 
$$\frac92 \left[ \frac19\sqrt{x} \sqrt{9+x} +\sinh^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{x}{9}}\right]^1_0$$ $$= \frac12 \left[\sqrt{10} + 9\sinh^{-1}\frac13 \right]$$

I have managed to get half of what the integral should be, my thoughts is that I've made a mistake somewhere in using an identity where Ii should have cancelled the half out. Any help would be great.

Comment: You substituted $dx$ incorrectly.

Comment: That's annoyed me now that it  was that simple.

Comment: Too many $9$s I guess.

Comment: A factor $18$ became $9$, as you probably have already discovered.